# How to access an English-Chinese dictionary database file correctly?

Tags: databaselink, dictionary

Now I have an English-Chinese dictionary database file (This database source file comes from [this website](https://download.csdn.net/download/u014466109/9829488?utm_medium=distribute.pc_relevant_download.none-task-download-OPENSEARCH-2.nonecase&depth_1-utm_source=distribute.pc_relevant_download.none-task-download-OPENSEARCH-2.nonecase) and this file can be downloaded by clicking ["点此下载"](http://wfscbw.cn/index.aspx?id=UDCZsDjUedf). After downloading, you can rename it). I want to find out all the words whose second letter is `b`. But I don't know how to access this database file:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite", "英语单词词典数据库 mysql版.sql"], 
  "Location" -> "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop", 
  "RelativePath" -> True]
SQLExecute[conn, "SELECT *b* FROM SAMPLETABLE"]
```

But the above code is invalid, I very much hope that you can provide as detailed help as possible, what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This SQL file is not a sqlite3 database file. I don't know whether Wolfram Mathematica includes a complete MySQL program. I installed the latest version of MariaDB/MySQL on my computer.

### 1. Install MariaDB/MySQL

To access this database file, you may need to install MySQL/MariaDB. Then you need to start the MySQL process and import the SQL file to MySQL.

In short, you need to run the following commands in the terminal,

```
> mysql -uroot -p 
MariaDB [(none)]> create database dictionary;
MariaDB [(none)]> use dictionary;
MariaDB [(dictionary)]> source ./words.sql
```

### 2. Link MySQL

Next, you need to link MySQL at Mathematica.

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
conn = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dictionary"], 
  "Username" -> "root", "Password" -> "$Prompt"]
```

If everything is ok, then you can now query.

```
Grid[Flatten@{#, 
     SQLExecute[conn, 
      "select cn from words where en='" <> # <> "'"]} & /@ {"is", 
   "here", "my"}, Frame -> All]
```

And results as follows,

[image]

**Note:** If you are using MySQL for the first time, you may need to reset the password. The relevant methods can be easily retrieved on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer!

Answer (score 3):

*(Not an answer, or a partial answer.)*

1. I am not sure how many people would be willing / prepared to click on buttons on a site with language they do not understand. I think using GitHub repositories like [this one](https://github.com/1eez/103976) is better.
2. I get that the question is about DatabaseLink and SQL querying, but I assume getting the words is the primary goal.
3. Can a [CSV file](https://github.com/1eez/103976/raw/master/EnWords.csv) be used instead?
4. The correct SELECT SQL statement is: `SELECT word FROM EnWords WHERE word LIKE '_b%'`
5. (I tried to import some English-Chinese SQL files into a local database, but have little success so far.)

### Getting the words from a GitHub hosted CSV file

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 dsEnglishChinese = 
   ResourceFunction["ImportCSVToDataset"]["https://github.com/1eez/103976/raw/master/EnWords.csv"];
 ]

Dimensions[dsEnglishChinese]

SeedRandom[32];
RandomSample[dsEnglishChinese, 6]

dsEnglishChinese[Select[StringMatchQ[#word, LetterCharacter ~~ "b" ~~ __] &]]
```

[image]